# Загрузка HTML и CSS файлов из String

Tags: android, java

Как в WebView загрузить HTML и CSS файлы которые находятся в String?

HTML и CSS файлы находятся, например, в String A и B.
C HTML все понятно, как его вывести...

```
mWebView.loadData(temp, "text/html", null);
```

А как добавить CSS, чтобы страничка отображалась нормально?
И еще JavaScript. 
Я понимаю, что можно сделать, чтобы все было в одном, но нужно по отдельности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохрании CSS в отдельный файл на карте памяти и заведи на него ссылку внутри HTML типа:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///sdcard/style.css" />
```

аналогично и с JavaScript'ом

Comment: а вариат загрузки со строки возможен? Насчет сохранения я думал, но он не подходит, у пользователя не должно сохраняться никаких промежуточных файлов...